# Український відповідник до слова "рітейлер"("ритейлер")

Tags: іменники, запозичені-слова, орфографія

У статті [На український ринок виходить найбільший у світі рітейлер товарів для дому](http://expres.ua/news/2017/12/22/277567-ukrayinskyy-rynok-vyhodyt-naybilshyy-sviti-riteyler-tovariv-domu) натрапила на цікаве слово **рітейлер** (за інформацією на сайті [Onlinecorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BB/) **ритейлер**). Які є українські відповідники до цього слова, бо в словнику синонімів не знайшла? І як правильно писати з **И** чи **І?**(на просторах інтернету значна частина статей з І, а з И ( російськомовні).

Answer (score 1):

[§ 90](http://izbornyk.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par90) Чинного правопису української мови говорить, що після ***д, т, з, с, ц, ж (дж), ч, ш, р*** перед приголосними пишуть **И** (так зване [правило дев'ятки](http://www.philology.kiev.ua/Lingur/art_17.htm)).

> в) **И** пишеться:
>
> 1) у загальних назвах після приголосних д, т, з, с, ц, ж (дж), ч, ш, р перед наступним приголосним: дизель, динамо, диплом, директор, методика; інститут, математика, стимул, текстиль, тип; зиґзаґ, позиція, фізичний; марксизм, силует, система; цистерна, цифра; жирандоль, режим, джигіт, джинси; речитатив, чичероне; ширма, шифр; бригада, риф, фабрика;

---

*Retail* перекладається як [*"уроздріб"*, *"роздрібний"*](https://www.m-translate.com.ua/en-uk/word-retail-translation#). У контексті [маркетингу](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retail) українським [відповідником](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F) є [`"роздрібна торгівля"`](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/retail).

Answer (score 0):

За аналогією до [гуртовик](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA/) можна утворити роздрібник. Таке слово вже можна зустріти в саме цьому значенні. Наприклад,

> На ринку представлені також кілька структур, які обрали нестандартний
>   спосіб забезпечення мереж паливом. Це, приміром, донецький **роздрібник**
>   «Параллель», який працює на ринку з 1995 року.

Також це слово запропонували на [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/reteiler).